# Push notification cheat inside app

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I want to create cheat for the tester to check the push notification. I have a working example from a web link and it's working. I hit the same web-link inside the app and received the success response but no notification. The Same thing is working from a web browser.

eg. I have API suppose www.example.com/send/notif/44 to send the notification to my iPhone 6 and I am calling it from my app dashboard screen notify button.

Please help.

Comment: It's really unclear what are you asking. What do you mean by "cheat for the tester"?

Comment: I want to allow a tester to check if he is getting the notification. So, I have added one button in the app screen to get a notification. On that button click, I am hitting the web link to get the notification. If I hit the same link from the browser it works but no luck from code.

Comment: which iOS version you are using in your device. from iOS 10 only, if app is in foreground notification can see.

Comment: I am using iOS 10 only but it's not showing only when I hit the link from app only. It works from other platforms (Postman, web browser).

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize 3 methods to receive remote notifications.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    <#code#>
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    <#code#>
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    <#code#>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If app is in foreground, it still receives push notification but not any banner is displayed by the OS. So, a tester should go to background immediately when they push that test button.

Comment: Alperen Thanks a lot. It's working. I just did what you suggested going to background immediately then only it work's.